# Trying to store the data type "bit" in phpmyadmin. I keep getting 1111111111111111111111111111111 for 0 and 1111111111111111111111111111111 for 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to store the data type "bit" in phpmyadmin. I keep getting 1111111111111111111111111111111 for 0 and 1111111111111111111111111111111 for 1. I have tried four different import methods and two different viewing methods, but always the same error. (It wouldn't be such a problem if I got two different values, but they are both 1111111111111111111111111111111.)

What am I doing wrong? I just want to store some true/false values.

Comment: I'd go voor TINYINY(1)

Comment: Although I agree this is a duplicate, I think it would serve the community if it remained here. I spent maybe an hour searching the keyword "1111111111111111111111111111111" and found nothing.

Followup question, "Am I misusing "bit" or is it fundamentally broken and without use to anyone?" I'd like to know what I SHOULD be using it for.

Comment: Are you sure about the duplicate? Unless the question is wrong he's asking about data entry in PhpMyAdmin, but that other question is about PHP code using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your PHP version. If you are on PHP version 7.1.x, try upgrading to a later version of PHP. I just switched to version 7.4.4 and it fixes this problem - storing as 1 or 0 instead of 1111111111111111111111111111111.